# How to recover from JVM subprocess running OOM?

Tags: process, jvm

I have two JVM processes A and B. Process A communicates with the user and uses B as a slave, to do heavy computation: `User -> A -> B.compute`

Yet the method `B.compute` can run out of memory for certain inputs (it is impossible to know which). In such case I want to inform the user, that the input data he gave me is not appropriate, and I want to restart B.

I found the following (not very detailed) solutions on google:

- catch the error in B `catch (OutOfMemoryException e)`
- use JVM option `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=restart-command`
- manually restart B from A

Which method is the most appropriate to use?

Please show a minimal (OS agnostic) working example.

Answer (score 1):

Letting the JVM terminate abruptly is never a good design for any kind of application.

If you know that there are situations that will cause this, I would design process B to monitor its own memory usage and then terminate processing of data if it is going to run out of memory.

You can do this as simply as:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long usedMem = (rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory()) / 1024 / 1024;
```

You could set a threshold on free memory where your B process will stop processing the input, throw away all results and inform A that this is an erroneous input.  The garbage collector will reclaim unused memory and return B to being ready for more input (if you really have to you could make an explicit call to System.gc() to force this but I wouldn't recommend it).

Comment: I would do it continually using a separate thread.  How often you do this will need some experimentation on your part to see how quickly the app fills up the heap. 
 Doing it this way you can react as soon as the amount of heap being used exceeds a certain threshold.